# How to find current screen/route in nested Tab.Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a custom TabBar for a Tab.Navigator that needs to have a different action when one of the tabs is selected based on what the current route is in the Stack Navigator component for that tab.

How can I inspect the currently displayed Stack.Screen inside of this custom TabBar? Trying to use the getRoute hook only shows me the parent screen that hosts that Tab.Navigator.

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBar={(props) => <BottomTabBar {...props} />}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeStack}
        initialParams={{showSuccess: route.params?.showSuccess}}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Alternate" component={AlternateScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

I can't pass the value in using tabBarOptions as I don't know what the selected route would be when the tab bar is created.

Comment: I ended up keeping track of the current screen outside the scope of the navigator, but will leave this open in case someone has a better solution.

Comment: That seems like a good solution to me. You can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up keeping track of the current screen outside the scope of the navigator as the built in Tab Navigator did not keep a reference to nested screens in a Stack Navigator like I was hoping it would.

Only needing to determine a difference between two screens, my crude hack was to have a current screen reference in a context hook and update that value in a useEffect hook when the relevant screen was mounted.

In whatever your provider is, have a currentScreen const like this:

```
const currentScreen = useRef('Closet');
```

Then, in your screens, destructure that value from the provider in the useContext hook:

```
const { currentScreen } = useContext(MyContext);
```

Then, in the same screen update that currentScreen value in a useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    currentScreen.current = 'NewScreen';
}, []);
```

Comment: Can you add some of the relevant code to make the answer more concrete?

Comment: Code added to the answer above

Answer (score 1):

just figured this out for ReactNavigation v6+

i use:

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
```

and then:

```
<Tab.Navigator 
   initialRouteName={'Tab-All'}
   screenOptions={screenOptions}
   screenListeners={{state: (e) => { currentTabIndex.current = e.data.state.index }}}
   initialLayout={{width, height}}
>
... // your screens go here
</Tab.Navigator>
```

CurrentTabIndex is just variable created by useRef
So as you might figure Tab.Navigator inherits some Navigator properties.